# Why is this piece of code printing out hi?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
z = print('hi')
```

I understand print functions returns literally nothing . So when I type
print(z) 
I get None value.
My question is why does the piece of code below print hi

```
>>> z = print('hi')
hi
>>> print(z) 
None
```

Why is this not happening

```
>>>x = max('Hello world')
w
```

Comment: You're basically asking why `print` function prints and why `max` function doesn't ?

Comment: Simpler things made complex and then they say programming is so hard.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> I understand print functions returns literally nothing.

Yes but, apparently, you don't understand that it *first prints out what you give it* and *then* returns nothing :-) That is what it's *meant* to do.

The `max`, in exactly the same way, does what *it* is specified to do, which is return the maximum item after *not* printing anything. The printing of `w` that you're seeing has nothing to do with what `max` is doing, it's because the Python REPL loop<sup>(a)</sup> will print out the result of any statement that isn't `None`:

```
>>> None
>>> 1
1
>>> "hello"
'hello'
>>> False
False
>>> True
True
>>> 0
0
>>> def retNone(): return None
... 
>>> def retOne(): return 1
... 
>>> retNone()
>>> retOne()
1
```

If you want `z` to be given the thing you're currently printing, you can just use:

```
z = 'hi'
```

or, for more complex cases, Python has formatting options for you, such:

```
showPi = "Pi is roughly {}".format(355/113)
```

Neither of those will print the string you're creating until you explicitly want to, or unless you're in the REPL loop.

---

<sup>(a)</sup> Yes, I *know* what the `L` stands for, I'm just following the time-honoured traditions of "ATM machine", "HIV virus" and "LCD display" as per the requirements of the "RAS syndrome" :-)